# Searching the name for a Kneser-like graph

Tags: graph-theory

For given $m<n$, consider the graph having as its nodeset the $m$-element subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$, with edges joining all pairs of nodes that have $m-1$ elements in common.

Is there an established name for that graph?

The above graph has the same nodes as the corresponding Kneser graph, but its edges differ: its node valency is $(n-m)m$, while the Kneser graph's node valency is $\left(n-m\atop m\right)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph

Comment: Settled. I just was told that such a graph is a "Johnson graph".  Oops, Ed Pegg also posted the same information - thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The graph is called a [Johnson graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph).